# Getting ElementNotVisibleException exception in firefox though i am able to select the elements by xpath

Tags: java, xpath, exception, selenium-webdriver

Code:

```
package com.selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Monster {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

        WebDriver window=new FirefoxDriver();
        try{
            window.get("https://my.monsterindia.com/login.html?src=http://my.monsterindia.com/my_monster.html&rand=5257");
            WebElement wb=window.findElement(By.id("BodyContent:txtUsername"));
            wb.sendKeys("shantanunandan8@gmail.com");
            window.findElement(By.id("BodyContent_txtPassword")).sendKeys("sha1nta1nu");
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            window.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='submit']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            window.findElement(By.name("cancel")).click();
            window.findElement(By.className("flyout_close")).click();
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            window.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='http://media.monsterindia.com/monster_2012/trans.gif']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            Alert alt=window.switchTo().alert();
            System.out.println("Massage from alert is "+alt.getText());
            alt.dismiss();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            window.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Cancel']")).click();
            System.out.println("Closing");
            window.close();
        }//catch close
        finally{
            window.close();
        }//finally close
    }//main close

}//class close
```

Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 47 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'omega-d52b83806', ip: '10.0.0.5', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86',   os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: 6eebd4ca-d637-45fa-91e3-c5f18d1d3568
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true,  cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true,  browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false,  locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=29.0.1}]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
at com.selenium.Monster.main(Monster.java:24)
 Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Element is not  currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'omega-d52b83806', ip: '10.0.0.5', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.preconditions.visible(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous580265852301620722webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8179)
at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous580265852301620722webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10814)
at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous580265852301620722webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10831)
at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous580265852301620722webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10836)
at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous580265852301620722webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10778)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not  currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'omega-d52b83806', ip: '10.0.0.5', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86',  os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: 6eebd4ca-d637-45fa-91e3-c5f18d1d3568
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=29.0.1}]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
at com.selenium.Monster.main(Monster.java:33)
 Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
 Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
 System info: host: 'omega-d52b83806', ip: '10.0.0.5', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
 Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.preconditions.visible(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous580265852301620722webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8179)
at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous580265852301620722webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10814)
at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous580265852301620722webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10831)
at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous580265852301620722webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10836)
at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/DOCUME~1/OMEGA/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous580265852301620722webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10778)
```

This is the complete exception which i got from the code. Though i am able to locate all element using the xpath which i have used in the program. Before including `Alert alt=window.switchTo().alert();` the code was working fine but after putting them inside the code i am getting these exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work on your code. Need these changes to make it work:

First :- Replace the following with below snippet, this resolved your first exception. The page has more than one element when you locate with the below `xpath`. It should be unique to what you want to use.

```
window.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='http://media.monsterindia.com/monster_2012/trans.gif']")).click();
```

replace with:-

```
window.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='main_resume']//div//a[6]")).click();
```

Second :- Remove the `Alert`. The alert is with in page. Please replace the below

```
Alert alt=window.switchTo().alert();
System.out.println("Massage from alert is "+alt.getText());
```

You can very well change it to:

```
window.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Ok']")).click();
```

Please do use `wait` instead of `Thread.sleep()`.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Hi Nitin, the problem is some time i get ElementNotVisible Exception at the login page for the login button because my code is able to enter email id and password but after that i am getting this exception. But when i try to run the same program for 2-3 times without any change in code it works for some time but again it gives me this exception. Why this is happening? I googled it but not got any satisfying answer. Seeking for help

Comment: I can see that by luking @ ur code, but as i said u need to change how you handle locating your `WebElement`. Please use `wait` to make this work.

Comment: Nitin does the size of the window matters? Because whenever i run the code in maximum size window it works fine but in small window it sometime runs and some time not. If u want i can upload a complete video of the output when i run the code and also i replaced Thread.sleep by window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); as you recommended

Comment: I don't think so it matters with that. Can you let me know @ which line this happens?

Comment: After this line i am getting that exception<<>> window.findElement(By.id("BodyContent_txtPassword")).sendKeys("sha1nta1nu"); . But now i added window.manage().window().maximize() in my code and from then onwards i am not getting ElementNotVisible Exception.

Comment: You mean the line where you click on `login` button? If so, can you see in your code if you have checked the `checkbox` below username or emailid text field. I think it's mandatory to check that option, if you select enter emailid.

Comment: No its not mandatory to check that checkbox. Yes i am getting ElementNotVisible Exception for the login button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54411/discussion-between-nitin-chawda-and-shantanu).

Answer (score 0):

whether below step leads to any alert. If so there wont be any problem. If not control goes to catch block (NoAlertPresentException) and then it tries to click on cancel button which is not visible. Just cross check your flow and locators.

```
window.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='http://media.monsterindia.com/monster_2012/trans.gif']")).click();
```

Comment: Sir the code window.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='http://media.monsterindia.com/monster_2012/trans.gif']")).click(); leads to delete button and as soon as you click that button a alert box opens which says "Are you sure to Delete this item" with two button "ok" and "cancel". The flow is also correct. Any other thing which i can try?